# powershell comparison of filename with date

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to list all files which are older than X days, but I need to run this comparison on the filename having "date" in "yyyyMMdd" format instead of the last modified time of the file.

Comment: What have you tried? You're more likely to get help here if you share what you've done so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The following script will ignore any prefix/suffix/extension to the date in the file name

---

```
$XDays = -20
$Until = (get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays($XDays)
"match files until {0}" -f $Until.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

# This RE will match any date in this century (but not validate it)
$RE = [RegEx]'^.*?(?<date>20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]).*$'

Get-ChildItem "*20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]*" | Sort BaseName| ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.BaseName -Match $RE){
        If ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches.date,'yyyyMMdd',$null) -le $Until){
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

To modify output from current dir format change the inner `$_` to `$_.FullName` or `$_.Name`

Sample output:

```
PS A:\> .\SO_45642524.ps1
match files until 20170723

    Directory: A:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170718suffix.txt
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170719suffix.txt
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170720suffix.txt
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170721suffix.txt
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170722suffix.txt
-a----       08/11/2017     23:35              8 prefix20170723suffix.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried this code snippet, but its not returning the desired files.
upto this mark Get-ChildItem "*20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]*", its all good. But inside the foreach, parseexact does not work. is it possible to store all the parsed dates in a property of another object?

Comment: Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45642524/edit) your question to supply a sample of your files names and what you expect. It's difficult to argue with missing details.

Comment: Hey there, It was an error on my side. I just made a small change in Regex and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file | where { $_.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -le "20111203" }
```

or this?

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file | where { (get-date $_.LastWriteTime -Format "yyyyMMdd") -le "20170803" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to strip your file name and convert the date part to a datetime value, after that you will be able to remove it. Here is an example of how to convert it to datetime:

```
gci -Filter *.txt | select Name, @{Name="DateFile"; Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName.substring(5),'yyyyMMdd',$null)}}
```

[image]

And to remove the files older than one week lets say, I would do it as follow:

```
gci -Filter *.txt | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="DateFile"; Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName.substring(5),'yyyyMMdd',$null)}} | Where-Object {$_.DateFile -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7)} | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName}
```